# What's this strange TortoiseSVN overlay icon?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN. The icon below suddenly shows up these days. I never saw it before. I cannot see clearly the details of the icon. Seems there's a letter.

What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: ask it here: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=4061

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the info.

Comment: keep in mind that windows supports only 15 (16?) different overlay icons. So if you use other applications reserving overlay icons, it will lead to this problems too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried update/cleanup/commit operation. All failed. After I delete the .svn folder and re-checkout the code, the strange overlay icon disappeared and the lovely red exclamation mark shows up.

So I guess this icon means the SVN has lost track of the files.

Anyway, I still haven't found the official explanation. Even here https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html.